# A circular garden of radius r (in feet) is going to have a 4 ft sidewalk build around it. Express the area of the sidewalk as a function of r.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A circular garden of radius r (in feet) is going to have a 4 ft sidewalk build around it. Express the area of the sidewalk as a function of r.

I first calculated the circumference (2)(3.14)(r) but don't know how to calculate the the area of the sidewalk.

Thank you.

Comment: area minus area

Answer (score 1):

small radius $=r $

big radius $=r+4$

small area $=\pi r^2$

big area $=\pi (r+4)^2=\pi (r^2+8r+16) $

the difference is ...